# Simple Json Example with android

Tags: android, json

I want to read JSON web service result.

My web service result is

```
[{"etkinlikTarihi":123,"eposta":"posta","etkinlikAdi":"ali","etkinlikDetay":"veli","etkinlikId":1},{"etkinlikTarihi":12,"eposta":"posta","etkinlikAdi":"ali","etkinlikDetay":"detay","etkinlikId":2},{"etkinlikTarihi":13,"eposta":"posta","etkinlikAdi":"mali","etkinlikDetay":"detay","etkinlikId":3},{"etkinlikTarihi":13,"eposta":"posta","etkinlikAdi":"mali","etkinlikDetay":"detay","etkinlikId":4}]
```

But, whenever I try to read with `JSONObject` in Android, I get a exception...

My code is here,

```
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(wsEtkinlikListesi);

String etkinlikTarihi = jsonResponse.getString("etkinlikTarihi");
```

And this is my stack trace:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"etkinlikAdi":"toplanti","etkinlikDetay":"toplan","etkinlikTarihi":1454648400000,"etkinlikId":5,"eposta":"sefagenel@gmail.com"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Where is my mistake and how can I correct it?

Comment: your response is json array not json object

Comment: you are handling the response as an Object, instead it is an Array of objects...

Comment: What in the error `type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` you don't understand?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to parse the array and then get every object on it:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jSonResultString);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonobject.getString("etkinlikTarihi");
    String url = jsonobject.getString("posta");
    ...
}
```